# Spark Context Issue

Tags: sql, json, apache-spark, pyspark

```
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('QUEUEVQL').getOrCreate()
    jsonStrings = {"Name": "SRIDHAR", "Author": "jangcy", "BlogEntries": 100, "Caller": "jangcy"}
    dt = [jsonStrings]
    dfs = spark.createDataFrame(dt).collect()
    dfs2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(dfs).toDF()
    dfs2.createOrReplaceTempView("QVQL")
    resDf = spark.sql("select Name from QVQL")
    resDfPandas = resDf.toPandas()
    print(resDfPandas)
```

Error for the Code :

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o490.collectToPython. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 27.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 27.0 (TID 98) (172.17.7.28 executor 1): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3.6": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)

Answer (score 1):

this should be a 2 liner, if your're still getting an error then you're missing some jar files as the error message indicates.

```
    jsonStrings = {"Name": "SRIDHAR", "Author": "jangcy", "BlogEntries": 100, "Caller": "jangcy"}
    dfs = spark.createDataFrame([jsonStrings]).toPandas()
    print(dfs)

  # Author  BlogEntries  Caller     Name
  # 0  jangcy          100  jangcy  SRIDHAR
```

Comment: Hi Jayrythium, Thnx for ur reply. But this code snippet runs on python console, when executed one by one, but fails when run on spark cluster. The Virtual Environemtn is same for both executions. Any Suggestions. Below are the libs used to Virtual Environment. Have added Libs in 2 Sections below.

Comment: Sec 1
attrs==21.2.0,  certifi==2020.12.5 , chardet==4.0.0 , click==8.0.1  , contextvars==2.4  , 
dataclasses==0.8  , Flask==1.1.2, Flask-Cors==3.0.10, h11==0.9.0, httpcore==0.11.1, 
httplib2==0.19.1, httptools==0.2.0, httpx==0.15.4, idna==2.10, immutables==0.15, 
importlib-metadata==4.0.1, itsdangerous==2.0.1, Jinja2==3.0.0, joblib==0.15.1, 
jsonpickle==1.4.2, jsonschema==3.2.0, MarkupSafe==2.0.1, mysql-connector-

Comment: Sec 2
python==8.0.25, 
numpy==1.19.5, pandas==1.1.4, protobuf==3.17.1, py4j==0.10.9, pymongo==3.10.1, 
pyparsing==2.4.7, pyrsistent==0.17.3, pyspark==3.1.2, python-dateutil==2.8.1, 
pytz==2021.1, requests==2.25.1, rfc3986==1.5.0, six==1.16.0, sniffio==1.2.0, 
typing-extensions==3.7.4.2, urllib3==1.26.4, Werkzeug==2.0.1, zipp==3.4.1

Comment: Not sure, I ran mine on spark 2.4. Curious to know why are you using spark to create pandas df?

Comment: remove the .toPandas() method  and instead of print(dfs) do dfs.show(). see if that works